# how to remove spaces between lines ENTIRELY on terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm writing a CLI 3d rendering program, and in order for it to display correctly, I want it not to have spaces between lines at all. is there a terminal that can change its line spacing to zero or any other solution?

Comment: "Spaces between lines"? What exactly do you mean by that? I guess you want https://github.com/stefanhaustein/TerminalImageViewer

Comment: Do you want to use `ncurses`?